# How to replace an element with another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div>something</div>
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
```

Now I want to replace that `<p>` with `<span>`. Something like this;

```
<div>something</div>
<span>this is a span</span>
```

---

I want something like this:

```
$("div").siblings("p"). /* replace with "<span>this is a span</span>" */
```

---

**Note:** There isn't any wrapper around that `<p>`. So I **cannot** use `.html()`.

---

Well, doing that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering given html, you can do it this way:

```
$("div").next("p").replaceWith('<span>This is a span</span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call. Consider this DOM structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner second">And</div>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

The second inner `<div>` could be replaced with the specified HTML:

```
$( "div.second" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
```

This results in the structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <h2>New heading</h2>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

See http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$('p').replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<span />", {html: $(this).html()});
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/k2swf/592/